# Value of $\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\log x}{1-x}dx$. What is my wrong step?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I would like to evaluate the value of this integral:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\log x}{1-x}dx.$$

---

On one hand, I proceed using integration by parts as follows:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g'(x)dx,$$
where $f(x)=\log x$ and $g'(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$. From this,  I can write: $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=-\log(1-x)$.

Therefore:
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}I=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g'(x)dx&=\left[f(x)g(x)\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}f'(x)g(x)dx,\\&=\left[-\log(1-x)\log x\right]_{0}^{1}+\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx,\\&=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx\\&=-\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\log(t)}{1-t}dt\\&=-I.\end{split}\end{equation}$$

Hence, $I=0.$

On the other hand, Wolframalpha gives $I=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}.$

Comment: In the step from the third-to-last line to the penultimate, you have forgotten to adjust the integral bounds. $$\int_{x=0}^{x=1} \frac{\log (1-x)}{x}\,dx = -\int_{1-t = 0}^{1-t=1} \frac{\log t}{1-t}\,dt = -\int_{t=1}^{t=0} \frac{\log t}{1-t}\,dt = \int_0^1 \frac{\log t}{1-t}\,dt = I.$$

Comment: My bad. I see the error. So $I=I$ and my method leads nowhere. I will try the method mentioned by Alex. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After integrating by parts, use the power series for $\log(1-x)$:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx = -\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}dx\\=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k}dx=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

Don't use integration by parts straight away. Instead, expand the denominator: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$ because the bounds on $x$ are strictly between $0$ and $1$. After this, interchange integration and summation (due to uniform convergence and you'll get integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{1} x^k \log x dx$. Now use integration by parts.